# How to combine rows or data into one row

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am working on a project to see how many units of each category that customers order and this is my Select clause:

```
   SELECT
     d2.customer_id
    , ( CASE WHEN d2.category = 100 THEN d2.units ELSE 0 END ) AS produce_units
    , ( CASE WHEN d2.category = 200 THEN d2.units ELSE 0 END ) AS meat_units
    , ( CASE WHEN d2.category = 300 THEN d2.units ELSE 0 END ) AS seafood_units                                  
    , SUM (d2.units) AS total_units
```

And my result looks like this while 62779 is customer id and the last column is total units.

```
   62779    0   0   0   0   20  0   0   0   0   0   0   20
   62779    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   52  0   0   52
   62779    0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6
   62779    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   22  0   22
   62779    0   0   0   0   0   14  0   0   0   0   0   14
   62779    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   20  0   0   0   20
   62779    0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8
   62779    64  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   64
```

However, I want my result to look like this:

```
   62779    64  6   0   8   20  14  0   20  52  22  0   206
```

Please advice. Thanks :)

Comment: `SELECT customer_id, SUM(..), SUM(...), SUM(...) FROM table GROUP BY customer_id`

Comment: @lad2025..better post it as an answer

Comment: Wow it is this simple but I've never thought of it. Thanks!!